# When writing TV scripts, is it heard of to change not only the characters but the type of story?

Tags: character-development, plot, script

I have an idea but before i run with it I need to know if you heard of a show going from, let's say, drama to fantasy. I have smooth transitions from one to the other and the B-plot  carries through. The only changes are the characters and the A and C-plots. I think it could work but I need more opinions on this.

Comment: Yes, network suits can seriously rework pilots/pitches so they barely resemble the original. They can do it with shows currently on the air; the most recent example would be "Up All Night."

Comment: If you're writing for an existing show, I have been told that if you are writing a "spec script" (TV script), you cannot send, say, Family Guy, a spec script with Family Guy characters. Family Guy writers are not allowed to read, or even look at, a script with their characters in it because, later on, the original author could come back and say the Family Guy writers stole their episode without giving them credit.

Comment: As written, this is a poll question. Are you writing a spec script? A script for an existing series? Are you a screenwriter for an existing series? If you have the authority to make the kind of change you're proposing, you should have a creative and production team to chew this over with. If not, you should be working within the boundaries of the show as-is.

Comment: If you're contemplating mapping out your own new entire series with a gradual shift in genre - well, that I could see being a question.

Comment: In case of cinematic movies - yes (if rarely), the (in)famous "From Dusk To Dawn" comes to mind. In case of TV series, not really, at least never a big shift - family drama into family sitcom, or crime into mystery, okay, but a crime drama into High Fantasy? nope.

Comment: Also note some shows do temporarily stray into different genres - like StarTrek 'holodeck' episodes - but that's not a permanent shift, just one-off episodes.

Answer (score 1):

They do it for know entities, they would NEVER trust an outsider to do it.

99% of the reject pile, most of it un-read, is from spin-offs of pre-existing movies or shows.

They are taking a big financial risk with newcomers; they don’t want what their average trusted minions can produce.

In other words If you ARE IN you can as mediocre as you want, but if you WANT IN your ideas, and execution  better be stellar.

Answer (score 1):

It will be risky, as long as fans know it is the same show. If not, you are essentially just creating a new show under the same name. It will also be difficult and if this show is one that lets writers have one or two chances at scripts before they move on to new talent (As some shows do) then you probably won't have the time to pull it off as you will need to slowly bring in the new era of the show, instead of just forcing it upon fans.